# Using special character (delta) in label text in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, labeling

I add a label text in ArcMap, but I would like that at the beginning of the text to show the symbol Delta as a Greek alphabet (Δ). I tried the unicode Python code (u+0394) but it didn't work.

I would like to get this -> ΔPM2.5 and I tried this -> 'u+0394' MP<sub>2,5</sub>, and u"u/0394" MP<sub>2,5</sub>, but I didn't get the delta letter.

Comment: For VBScript, it is `ChrW(&h0394) &"PM2.5"` . 
For Python, it is `u"\u0394" + "PM2.5"`.  Since ArcMap uses Python 2.x, you have to explicitly tell it you are using a unicode string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way is to copy the character from the Windows Character Map and paste it into the text. Note parser has to be VBScript.

[image: Character Map]